# mismatched std::allocator for some of STL containers

Tags: c++, stl, containers, language-lawyer, allocator

Is it technically valid to use mismatched `std::allocator` specialization (surely, except its specialization for `void`) as a template parameter for STL containers (not all of them, but enumerated below plus unordered_(multi)map/set)? Following code compiles fine.

```
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    struct A { bool operator < (A) const { return true; } };
    struct B {};
    struct C {};
    std::list< A, std::allocator< C > > l;
    std::forward_list< A, std::allocator< C > > fl;
    std::deque< A, std::allocator< C > > d;
    std::set< A, std::less< A >, std::allocator< C > > s;
    std::multiset< A, std::less< A >, std::allocator< C > > ms;
    std::map< A, B, std::less< A >, std::allocator< C > > m;
    std::multimap< A, B, std::less< A >, std::allocator< C > > mm;
}
```

I believe this is due to allocator being immediately rebound to underlying node type without any relation to its source type.

Comment: I'd say it could be undefined behavior, but I don't know (maybe the allocator is the same for the different types anyway)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say this is *UB* (at least in C++11) because specifying an allocator which has a different `value_type` from the `value_type` of the container violates the *allocator-aware container requirements* which means those instances do not conform to the general container requirements. Furthermore, I can't find anything in the C++11 standard that says that the allocator types are to be rebound from the type provided as template parameter.

---

1. Section `[container.requirements.general]` tells us:

> 13) All of the containers defined in this Clause and in (21.4) except array meet the additional requirements of an allocator-aware container, as described in Table 99.

2. The *Allocator-aware container requirements* says:

> Requires: `allocator_type::value_type` is the same as `X::value_type`.

3. Section `[default.allocator]` specifies

> `typedef T value_type;`

as a member of the `allocator` template in namespace `std`.

4. Section `[multimap.overview]` contains:

```
template <class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
    class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key, T> > >
class multimap {
    [...]
    typedef Allocator allocator_type;
    [...]
 };
```

(With similar findings for the other containers.)

Comment: Points 1 + 2 are sufficient.

Comment: @orient: No because the typedef in point 4 could read something like `typedef typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<value_type> allocator_type;` which would make the picture a little different.

Comment: Additional info:  libc++ catches this UB at compile-time with a `static_assert`.

Comment: Additional additional info: libstdc++ intentionally doesn't catch this because we support it as a conforming extension, but I've been meaning to add static assertions for strict modes when extensions are not wanted.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, _"I can't find anything in the C++11 standard that says that the allocator types are to be rebound"_ Even if it doesn't say so, they _must_ be for most allocator-aware containers in the standard to work, all of them except `basic_string` and `vector` (even `vector<bool>` will rebind). That was clarified as a defect report: http://wg21.link/lwg2218

Comment: @JonathanWakely : Why would you rebind an allocator which has the proper value_type?

Comment: @Pixelchemist, I'm not sure I even understand your question. What is the proper value_type for `std::list<T, A>` to allocate its internal node types? It's certainly not `A` because that allocates memory for objects of type `T`. What is the proper value_type for `std::deque<T, A>` to allocate the table of pointers to its pages? It's not `A`. Maybe you should consider how an allocator with the proper value_type can ever be provided to those containers when (as you quoted!) the containers require that "`allocator_type::value_type` is the same as `X::value_type`." They _must_ rebind.

Comment: @JonathanWakely : Absolutely. I'm too much into thinking along the Tracks of vector.

Comment: @Pixelchemist, I specifically said that `basic_string` and `vector` don't need to rebind :-) So _"Why would you rebind an allocator which has the proper value_type?"_ You wouldn't. But usually it has the wrong value type, so you need to.